# PHP My query is working in phpmyadmin but not in my code

Tags: php, mysql, vtiger

So i made use this query to get the details about changes and mail it. It previously worked when the seconde inner join was missing but what ever i do i cant make it work with it. In phpmyadmin it works and i get my rows but in my php i get 0 rows. i would love to know what im doing wrong here.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM vtiger_modtracker_detail WHERE id = (SELECT vtiger_modtracker_detail.id FROM vtiger_modtracker_detail " .
"INNER JOIN vtiger_modtracker_basic ON vtiger_modtracker_basic.id = vtiger_modtracker_detail.id " .
"INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity ON vtiger_crmentity.modifiedtime = vtiger_modtracker_basic.changedon " .
"WHERE vtiger_crmentity.crmid = ? ORDER BY vtiger_modtracker_detail.id DESC LIMIT 1);";

$res = $adb->pquery($query, array($id[1]));
$row = $adb->num_rows($res);
```

EDIT:

I simplified the query a bit but nothing changed.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM vtiger_modtracker_detail WHERE id = (SELECT vtiger_modtracker_basic.id FROM vtiger_modtracker_basic " .
"INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity ON vtiger_crmentity.modifiedtime = vtiger_modtracker_basic.changedon " .
"WHERE vtiger_crmentity.crmid = 42 ORDER BY vtiger_modtracker_basic.id DESC LIMIT 1)";
```

It could be because im comparing dates in the INNER JOIN.

EDIT 2: missing $ at pquery() but this did not fix it. I have found a work around so i dont need to use this query anymore. but if someone does know whats wrong with the query i would love to know.

EDIT 3: Work around did not work Still need an answer on this.

Comment: So does it work in phpmyadmin with the second inner join? Maybe a stupid question, but do you have data in your tables?

Comment: Can you tell me what `$res = $adb->pquery($query, array(id[1]));` is supposed to be, specifically the *id[1]*? Is it actually `$id[1]` in your code? What type of object is your `$adb`?

Comment: @Timothy Yes the data does exist and can be queryed in phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Davis $adb is the db connection class, pquery is a function that prepares the query(fill question marks with the second parameter) and runs the execute function. $id[1] is the the id that i get from the $entity. the value is in the format of module_idxentity_id. i use explode on x to get entity id. i have checked the value of $id[1] before and after the query by printing it to a file. if i use the same id in my query in phpmyadmin i get results.

Comment: If you execute just the inner query (the `SELECT vtiger_modtracker_basic.id FROM` part) through your db connection object, does it work? Or something even more simple? Have you tried a query that doesn't bind any variables, something super simple? And then if you add in a single bind does it still work? Perhaps there's an issue with your "db connection class" (but probably not, since you no doubt use it elsewhere).

Comment: @Davis Just like you said it works every where. The only moment it does not work is with the inner join of modifiedtime. this is a datetime field so i was thinking that that may be the problem but then again i dont know why it would be a problem. btw i did the inner query only and again the same results. works in phpmyadmin no results in the code.

Answer (score 0):

add `'` before each name in the query:

```
SELECT 'vtiger_modtracker_detail.id' FROM 'etc', 'etc2'
```

Comment: thnx for the anwer. i have found a work around so in this case i wont be using this query but ill be using quotes more.

Comment: my workaround failed so i tryed your solution but it did not change any thing nor did it work with ` .

Comment: Have you placed ALL sql names (tables, fields, etc.) in '`'? if so, if you copy/paste your PHP sql query in phpmyadmin, does it execute without errors? Also, can you execute any other query from that client in that database?

Comment: You can't use single quotes/apostrophes around table and column names--did you mean backticks ```? Your second comment suggests that's what you mean (in which case you may want to edit your answer for clarity, even if that didn't work for the asker).

Comment: @Bonatti Yes i did replace all and in case of the backticks it worked in phpmyadmin but still not in the code. Also i can execute other querys. If this wasnt possible the crm would not work as it gets a lot of stuff from db.